# Why is laravel (eloquent) caching last response from api route?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, socket.io, eloquent

I'm building reactive dashboard with Laravel / VueJS. When dashboard is working and socket connection is up, my idea is to synchronize all clients with same userId and after reconnecting I'm sending request to the endpoint and I'm `synchronized` again. The synchronization is needed beacause all users can actually change some configurations to dashboard like chosing grid items or resize them or drag them into another place.

I'm challenging the issue when after reconnecting to sockets I'm firing request to database to get the data again and I'm getting the same response as I did for the init request. Data is not updated.

But when I disconnect again and connect once more. Data is synchronized again. And I'm getting data updated for the second call.

I tohught thats because of Cache-control headers but It grants nothing to me.

I tried to change headers on api.

```
return response()->json($response, 200, [
    'Cache-Control' => 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate'
]);
```

And for axios:

```
axios.get(payload.url, {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Cache-Control' : 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate'
    }
}).then( response => {
```

But it still doesnt work.

My eloquent call is:

```
$dashboards = Dashboard::where(
        'user_id', '=', $userId
    )->with([
    'layouts',
    'components' => function($query) {
        $query->with('config')->with('type');
    }
])->get();
```

Headers for first call are like:

```
Cache-Control: must-revalidate, no-cache, no-store, private
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 2564
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Sat, 26 May 2018 12:06:34 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=96
Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.0g PHP/7.2.1
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.1
X-RateLimit-Limit: 100
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 90
```

For the second call I'm getting

```
Cache-Control: must-revalidate, no-cache, no-store, private
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 2564
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Sat, 26 May 2018 12:07:29 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.0g PHP/7.2.1
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.1
X-RateLimit-Limit: 100
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 94
```

Why is this synchronization works for the second request not for the first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything seems to be okay, it was probably about the Vue and asynchronous action call. I managed to fix it with the help of `Promise`. However, the problem with the cache also appears after using the browser history (going back in browser like chrome). The strange thing is that the headers appear in the old version `Laravel`. The above headers along with `max-age = 0` should force the cache refresh.